# Sqlalchemy not working with python-oracledb and asking for tnsnames.ora directory

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, python-oracledb

no configuration directory to search for tnsnames.ora appears everytime even tho oracledb.connect is working

Please tell me what this tnsnames.org is. I have no idea and how to even find its directory? And how to implement it....i cant find an answer anywhere everywhere they just tell to set directory but dont tell how to find the directory

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007

Comment: Here are links about tnsnames.ora files and SQLAlchemy with python-oracledb that you will find useful: 1. https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optional-oracle-net-configuration-files 2. https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c 3. https://medium.com/gitconnected/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19

Answer (score 1):

It is not tnsnames.**org** but .**ora** (wrong extension; if you were looking for tnsnames.org no wonder you didn't find it).

It is a file that contains aliases to all databases you use. It is located in directory (folder) you used to install Oracle software; narrow search to its `\network\admin` folder.

If you install more than one Oracle software product (for example, XE database and Oracle Developer Suite (Forms and Reports)), each installation creates its own `tnsnames.ora` file. It means that - when you get access to a new database and want it to be accessible from all Oracle software you use - you have to maintain not just one, but two (or more) `tnsnames.ora` files. That's *stupid*.

Instead, create environment variable named `tns_admin` which points to a single directory (folder)/`tnsnames.ora` file. For example, on my computer (running MS Windows):

```
C:\>set tns_admin
TNS_ADMIN=C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\0_Oracle_library
```

Now, whenever I have to add a new database alias, I open `tnsnames.ora` file located in that directory and edit it.

When you just start with Oracle, you probably have only one database available. As the time goes by, new databases are available to you (depending on projects you work on). Currently, my `tnsnames.ora` contains 62 entries.

Comment: With 62 entries in your `tnsnames.ora` you may consider to use the Oracle Internet Directory, to provide common (and consistent) aliases for all databases in your premises.